# Google Application Credentials set and not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, google-cloud-platform, google-authentication, google-cloud-vision

I have an Amazon EC2 with Linux Instance set up and running for my Java Web Application to consume REST requests. The problem is that I am trying to use Google Cloud Vision in this application to recognize violence/nudity in users pictures.

Accessing the EC2 in my Terminal, I set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS by the following command, which I found in the documentation:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<my_json_path.json>
```

Here comes my first problem: When I restart my server, and ran 'echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS' the variable is gone. Ok, I set it to the bash_profile and bashrc and now it is ok.

But, when I ran my application, consuming the above code, to get the adult and violence status of my picture, I got the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
```

My code is the following:

*Controller*:

```
        if(SafeSearchDetection.isSafe(user.getId())) {
            if(UserDB.updateUserProfile(user)==false){
                throw new SQLException("Failed to Update");
            }
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Explicit Content");
        }
```

*SafeSearchDetection.isSafe(int idUser)*:

```
    String path = IMAGES_PATH + idUser + ".jpg";

    try {
        mAdultMedicalViolence = detectSafeSearch(path);
        if(mAdultMedicalViolence.get(0) > 3)
            return false;
        else if(mAdultMedicalViolence.get(1) > 3)
            return false;
        else if(mAdultMedicalViolence.get(2) > 3)
            return false;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
```

*detectSafeSearch(String path)*:

```
    List<AnnotateImageRequest> requests = new ArrayList<AnnotateImageRequest>();
    ArrayList<Integer> adultMedicalViolence = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    ByteString imgBytes = ByteString.readFrom(new FileInputStream(path));

    Image img = Image.newBuilder().setContent(imgBytes).build();
    Feature feat = Feature.newBuilder().setType(Type.SAFE_SEARCH_DETECTION).build();
    AnnotateImageRequest request = AnnotateImageRequest.newBuilder().addFeatures(feat).setImage(img).build();
    requests.add(request);

    ImageAnnotatorClient client = ImageAnnotatorClient.create();

    BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response = client.batchAnnotateImages(requests);
    List<AnnotateImageResponse> responses = response.getResponsesList();

    for (AnnotateImageResponse res : responses) {
        if (res.hasError()) {
            System.out.println("Error: "+res.getError().getMessage()+"\n");
            return null;
        }

        SafeSearchAnnotation annotation = res.getSafeSearchAnnotation();
        adultMedicalViolence.add(annotation.getAdultValue());
        adultMedicalViolence.add(annotation.getMedicalValue());
        adultMedicalViolence.add(annotation.getViolenceValue());

    }
    for(int content : adultMedicalViolence)
        System.out.println(content + "\n");

    return adultMedicalViolence;
```

Answer (score 0):

My REST application was built above a Tomcat8. After no success running the command:

```
System.getenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS")
```

I realize that my problem was in the Environment Variables to Tomcat installation. To correct this, I just created a new file setenv.sh in my /bin with the content:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<my_json_path.json>
```

And it worked!